# Suite CRM- Modifications are removed after Repair and Rebuilt

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

i have to add label for a custom created field in Contacts subpanel of Accounts. i have modified with another label name in the custom Ext folder of accounts. But after the Repair and rebuilt the modifications are changed to the previous settings. Please help me on in which file i have to modify. I have modified the custom folder only! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to add a label is to create a file under /custom/Extension/modules/Contacts/Ext/Language. You can name the file whatever you would like such as my_field.lang.php. Once you add the label do a Quick Repair & Rebuild and it will rebuild the /custom/modules/Contacts/Ext/Language/en_us.lang.ext.php file and include your new label.

The same steps apply for the Accounts module if it needs to be in there instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replay. I did the same you have suggested.But still the label is missing in the custom non-db field i have created for the 'Contacts sub panel' of accounts. The custom field item is listing but it's title label is missing. For the sub panel, is there any other way to make the label. Thanks.